# CSS3 to corner crop an image

Tags: html, css

Is there a css3 method that would allow you to diagonally corner crop an image?

[image]

I have a white/grey box variant in the works -- for solid colors -

```
.item:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 40px solid #dddddd;
    border-left: 40px solid #ffffff;
    width: 0;
}


.item:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 40px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 40px solid #dddddd;
    width: 0;
}
```

---

one of the big issues now though

is the polygon is using %'s -- so if the divs are different sizes -- the corners look different

[image]

Comment: no its nothing like that

Comment: Check out this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/#toc-animation-of-clip-path

Comment: Is there a more simple solution - to just not showing two corners lol - the problem is also making it responsive etc..

Comment: clip-path: polygon(0% 30%, 30% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 0% 100%); -- this clips it the other way -- this seems so convuluted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite the right dimensions, and you'll have to adjust based on your image height/width, but here's a little example that could work:

```css
.clipit {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - 30px) 0%, 100% calc(0% + 30px), 100% 100%, calc(0% + 30px) 100%, 0% calc(100% - 30px));
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - 30px) 0%, 100% calc(0% + 30px), 100% 100%, calc(0% + 30px) 100%, 0% calc(100% - 30px));
}
```

```html
<img class="clipit" src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/865/stairs-of-light-1532779.jpg" />
```

This page could be really useful to you: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Basically: `clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - 30px) 0%, 100% calc(0% + 30px), 100% 100%, calc(0% + 30px) 100%, 0% calc(100% - 30px));`:

- Point 1 at 0% (width), 0% (height)
- Point 2 at 100% - 30px (width), 0% (height)
- Point 3 at 100% (width), 0% + 30px (height)
- etc.

Comment: -- needs to be the other way -- how do you work out these polygon shapes - what do these numbers represent - and do they need to be this many?

Comment: -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0);

Comment: OK - I've flipped it

Comment: ... and added an explanation

Comment: __Just updated the main ticket -- the problem is though -- that the clipping masks will look different for different sized blocks

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. you would have to use clip-path:

```
    .item{
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0);
      clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0);
    }
```

here's an example with a image and div with a background:
http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/vXOZmG

You cant create your own polygons here: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: -- needs to be the other way -- how do you work out these polygon shapes - what do these numbers represent - and do they need to be this many?

Comment: needs to be the other way? the numbers are coordinates, so there's six pairs, one for each corner. with these points they draw a polygon.

Comment: -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0);

Comment: _ yes my example is actually backwards -- the designer has it actually the other way - was looking for a principle solution --- does this mean I should use this clipping method for the other boxes -- does this just work on images?

Comment: it works with other items i updated my codepen with a example with a div with a background color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122866/discussion-between-niles-tanner-and-the-old-county).

Comment: __Just updated the main ticket -- the problem is though -- that the clipping masks will look different for different sized blocks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

You can design your own clip path angles. (Designer does not appear to work in Firefox)

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 90%, 90% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 90%, 90% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

The 10% is the top left corner, the 90% is the bottom right.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8wpK.png)

Comment: __Just updated the main ticket -- the problem is though -- that the clipping masks will look different for different sized blocks